# cloudera/quickstart container missing files in /home/cloudera/

Tags: docker, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I pulled the latest **cloudera/quickstart** image and ran the following command:

```
docker run 
--hostname=quickstart.cloudera 
--privileged=true 
-t 
-i  
-p 8888:8888 
-p 7180:7180
-p 80:80 
-p 50070:50070 
-v $(pwd):/home/cloudera
-w /home/cloudera
cloudera/quickstart 
/usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

After doing so, I moved into the */home/cloudera* directory to run *./cloudera-manager*. Unfortunately, the file doesn't exist. Even worse, this directory is completely empty!

Anybody run into this issue or know a good way of debugging this problem?

Comment: Does you `$(pwd)` contain the files needed. What command are you using to go into the container to /home/cloudera

Comment: Yes,  $(pwd) has the files I need. I am using 'cd'. Is there a different command I should be using to change directories?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below

docker run 
--hostname=quickstart.cloudera 
--privileged=true 
-t 
-i
-p 8888:8888 
-p 7180:7180
-p 80:80 
-p 50070:50070 
cloudera/quickstart 
/usr/bin/docker-quickstart -d

Then cloudera-manager can be started from ./home/cloudera/cloudera-manager

Comment: It worked. Could you explain how your solution fixed my problem?

Comment: This isn't the complete solution as it doesn't enable me to mount the container's directory. Could you please provide this functionality and I will accept the answer.

Comment: I have removed mount option and just ran the container in detached mode. I think to mount the container we should run the image using  -d ( which run background)  and to pass -v mount flag please try  "$(pwd)"/target:/home/cloudera should help.